# what is the output of this python code? I got confused

Tags: python, python-3.x

It shows error but many say the output is " Learn PY 23 "
how is that possible?!

```
**def m(name,age=20)
    print(name,age)
m("learnPY",23)**
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: You should not have the ** at the start and end. Those are probably markers from a book or tutorial, not actual parts of the code

Comment: as well as the **, after the def statement, you need a `:`

Comment: The ```**``` probably come from bold formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By considering your code as below(removed **)

```
def m(name,age=20)
    print(name,age)
m("learnPY",23)
```

In function m argument age is given default value, which is applied only if you don't pass 2nd argument while calling function.

In your code you have it with 23 so,
the output will be  `"LearnPY 23"`

If you call `m("learnPY")` then
the output will be `"LearnPY 20"`

Comment: Thanks @Luke Borowy for differentiate the code part

Answer (score 1):

The code is not syntactically legal Python code.

Hence, the question "what is the output of this Python code" is non-sensical, because it *isn't* Python code.

Comment: This would work better as a comment, to make sure the OP is actually trying to run the code as shown.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. The thing is that the code is wrong formatted.

```py
def m(name,age=20):
  print(name,age)

m("learnPY",23)
```

If you run it correctly, it will work. This is because you're calling the function passing two arguments that will be printed.